# Handling errors mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm setting up routes to **login** and **sign up**, with *NodeJs* and *Express*.
I handle my errors in my backend, which send it to my front so I can display the message.

I succeeded to deal with every error I wanted, but there is one left that makes me struggle.

I have this error when I try to create a new User, with the same email address than an other User :

```
(node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: my.collection index: email_1 dup key: { email: "test@test.com" }
```

So that's great ! I can handle it then, but I don't know why I cant get the response I want.
Here is what I did :

Here is my `controller to sign up` :

```
const { signUpErrors, signInErrors } = require('../utils/errors.utils')

module.exports.signUp = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, firstname, lastname, address, mobilePhone } = req.body
    const user = await UserModel.create({ email, password, firstname, lastname, address, mobilePhone })
    const infoForJWT = user._id
    const token = createToken({ infoForJWT })

    if (!user) {
        const errors = signUpErrors(err)
        return res.status(200).send({ errors })
    } else {
        return res.send({ token })
    }
}
```

Here is my `utils file`, where I handle **Errors** :

```
module.exports.signUpErrors = (err) => {
    let errors = { email: '', password: '' }

    if (err.message.includes('email'))
        errors.email = "Incorrect e-mail or already taken."

    if (err.message.includes('password'))
        errors.password = "The password should be at least 6 characters."

    if (err.code == 11000)
        errors.email = "This e-mail is already registered"

    return errors
}
```

I thought that with `if (err.message.includes('email'))`, I would handle the error, but it does not.

Any idea, how I can handle this particular error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap the async operation in a try..catch block like so:

```
try {
   const user = await UserModel.create({ email, password, firstname, lastname, address, mobilePhone })
   const infoForJWT = user._id
   const token = createToken({ infoForJWT })
   res.send({ token })
  } catch (e) {
      // handle the error
      const errors = signUpErrors(e)
      return res.status(200).send({ errors })
}
```